# What are these comments next to postgres processes in ps?

Tags: process, postgresql, ps

When you run a Postgres database and check all the processes with `ps` you can see comments which most likely are neither executing program name, nor its parameters. What are they?

```
 $ ps ax | grep [p]ostgres:
 1066 ?        Ss     0:00 postgres: checkpointer process                                                                                
 1067 ?        Ss     0:00 postgres: writer process                                                                                      
 1068 ?        Ss     0:00 postgres: wal writer process                                                                                  
 1069 ?        Ss     0:00 postgres: autovacuum launcher process                                                                         
 1070 ?        Ss     0:00 postgres: stats collector process
```

I am not sure if this is specific to Postgres in any way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any program can change what `ps` calls it, see `man 3 setproctitle` :

```
NAME
     setproctitle — set process title

LIBRARY
     Utility functions from BSD systems (libbsd, -lbsd)

SYNOPSIS
     #include <sys/types.h>
     #include <bsd/unistd.h>

     void
     setproctitle_init(int argc, char *argv[], char *envp[]);

     void
     setproctitle(const char *fmt, ...);

DESCRIPTION
     The setproctitle() library routine sets the process title that appears on
     the ps(1) command.
```